# Find fileS and then find a string in those files

Tags: python, wordpress, content-management-system, cpanel

I have written a function that finds all of the version.php files in a path.  I am trying to take the output of that function and find a line from that file.  The function that finds the files is:

```
def find_file():
  for root, folders, files in os.walk(acctPath):
    for file in files:
      if file == 'version.php':
        print os.path.join(root,file)
find_file()
```

There are several version.php files in the path and I would like to return a string from each of those files.

Edit:
Thank you for the suggestions, my implementation of the code didn't fit my need.  I was able to figure it out by creating a list and passing each item to the second part.  This may not be the best way to do it, I've only been doing python for a few days.

```
def cmsoutput():
  fileList = []
  for root, folders, files in os.walk(acctPath):
    for file in files:
      if file == 'version.php':
        fileList.append(os.path.join(root,file))

  for path in fileList:
    with open(path) as f:
      for line in f:
        if line.startswith("$wp_version ="):
          version_number = line[15:20]
          inst_path = re.sub('wp-includes/version.php', '', path)
          version_number = re.sub('\';', '', version_number)
          print inst_path + " = " + version_number

cmsoutput()
```

Comment: Which string do you want to return? Based on what criteria?

Comment: The string I am looking for is "$wp_version =", there is no additional criteria other than its existence.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to use the output of your function, you have to `return` something. Printing it does not cut it. Assuming everything works it has to be slightly modified as follows:

```
import os


def find_file():
    for root, folders, files in os.walk(acctPath):
        for file in files:
            if file == 'version.php':
                return os.path.join(root,file)

foundfile = find_file()
```

Now variable `foundfile` contains the path of the file we want to look at. Looking for a string in the file can then be done like so:

```
with open(foundfile, 'r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    for lines in content:
        if '$wp_version =' in lines:
            print(lines)
```

Or in function version:

```
def find_in_file(string_to_find, file_to_search):
    with open(file_to_search, 'r') as f:
        content = f.readlines()
        for lines in content:
            if string_to_find in lines:
                return lines

# which you can call it like this:
find_in_file("$wp_version =", find_file())
```

Note that the function version of the code above will terminate as soon as it finds one instance of the string you are looking for. If you wanna get them all, it has to be modified.